# how to increase cache memory in centos

Tags: caching, centos

I have been facing a insuffient space in "/var/cache/yum"  directory.  Due to this my GUI of centos crashes.

I want to increase the size of cache directory. Also want to know the actual size of cache memory in servers?

Comment: Why don't you just clear the cache directory. Nothing bad will happen.

Comment: its a temporary solution. i want to increase the cache memory so that i don't face this problem ahead

Comment: Well basically you can't without any repartitioning. And due to the fact your question belongs more to this [stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30286/can-i-configure-my-linux-system-for-more-aggressive-file-system-caching) site, maybe you can find something appropriate their.

Comment: how to do repartitioning without loss of data ??

Comment: As I already said: Your questions belongs to the unix-stackexchange. Please move your questions there.

Comment: thanks i will post there.